# click event and moving the mouse

Tags: javascript, events

Is the `click` (or `contextmenu`, `dblclick`) event fired if, between the press and release of the mouse button, the mouse is moved within the object the event is bound to? Does it depend on the browser?

At least for clicking on a link, the click event seems to be canceled if I move the mouse. But for other types of clicks, it looks like they are fired sometimes. I am not sure if my observation is right.

Comment: Sawa, my guess it it would be dependent upon the user's configuration of their operating system. Also, there's a certain tolerance for how many pixels the mouse can move between clicks if a dblclick event is to be triggered. For example, this tolerance is very low on my mouse, but with my wacom tablet, the pen tip can move much further between clicks and still trigger a dblclick.

Comment: @naomik Does that mean movement tolerance between press and release within a click may be different from that between release of a click and press of the next click? Also, when a pen moves, does it trigger the same kind of event (`mousemove`) as with mouses? Maybe these might be additional questions that someone might answer.

Comment: hmm, I hadn't considered that (re: tolerance of movement between `mouseup` and `mousedown`). Some more research is definitely required here. As for `mousemove` with my pen, yes. The pen is just another controller on the cursor; it looks like the browser can't distinguish it from a mouse (with the exception of loading the wacom js lib to utilize wacom-specific features).

Answer (score 1):

Then event is triggered after the release when the mouse is pressed and released on the bound object

```
The click event is sent to an element when the mouse pointer is over the element, 
and the mouse button is pressed and released.
```

I know this is jQuery, but it explains it well: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Thanks. Does this come from your knowledge, or is the description you mentioned the only source? From your citation, it is not clear enough whether movement is allowed or not. It can be read in either way.